# Backpack for Laravel charts, append sum to chart

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-charts

As I'm trying to implement charts into Backpack for Laravel, I been stuck for a few hours on this problem. The following script gets the number of users created for each day and appends them to an array that is then shown on the charts.

```
        for ($days_backwards = 7; $days_backwards >= 0; $days_backwards--) {
        // Could also be an array_push if using an array rather than a collection.
        $users = Users::whereDate('created_at', today()->subDays($days_backwards))->count();
        $user[] = $users;
    }
```

Every iteration of the loop adds a number to the array (or is it a collection??) so something like [2,5,10,9,...].

I would rather like to get the total amount of users that ever registered, incrementally for each day, so that the result would be someting like [2,7,17,26,...].

I figured I could add each iteration with array_sum() but it's not working. Is it an array anyways? Is there a way to append to this list the sum to its previous?

Answer (score 1):

Well I kind of figured out!

```
$sum = 0;
for ($days_backwards = 7; $days_backwards >= 0; $days_backwards--) {
    $users  = Users::whereDate('created_at', today()->subDays($days_backwards))->count();
    $sum    = $sum + $users;
    $user[] = $sum;
}
```

It works!